# sails debug command not working in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, sails.js, node-inspector

I am creating my first `sails.js` app. When I tried

```
sails debug
```

I'm getting the following error on my command prompt

```
Debugger listening on port 5858
info: Starting app...

error: Grunt :: Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1129:14)
    at listen (net.js:1155:10)
    at Agent.Server.listen (net.js:1240:5)
    at Object.start (_debugger_agent.js:20:9)
    at startup (node.js:86:9)
    at node.js:814:3
```

To get the PID of the process using port:5858, I tried running

```
C:\Windows\system32>netstat -a -n -o
```

but unfortunately there is no process bound to port 5858. Am I missing something here?

I'm using Windows 8.1 with `node.js` `v0.12.0` and `sails.js` `0.11.0`

Comment: Yeah my server uses node 0.10.38 with sails because of some weird unfixed grunt thing.  Haven't puiled up this issue in a while, looks like there's new activity, check out this comment in particular: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2670#issuecomment-92140615

Comment: Perfect. it worked. It will be great if you can post this as an answer to my question so that i can accept the same. The question will still remain opened otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My server uses node 0.10.38 with sails because of some weird unfixed grunt thing with 11+.  Haven't pulled up this issue in a while, but it looks like there's new activity... check out [this comment in particular](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2670#issuecomment-92140615), which explains the issue and a possible fix (direct quote):

> Possible Solution:
>
> Looking at the options for child_process.fork, the --debug flag is being passed down to the child upon exiting the womb i.e. running
>   sails debug :
>
> ```
> // ./node_modules/sails/bin/sails-debug.js
>
> // Spin up child process for Sails
> Womb.spawn('node', ['--debug', pathToSails, 'lift'], {
>     stdio: 'inherit'
> });
> ```
>
> > setting options.execArgv to an empty array removes the flag and allows the process to continue:
>
> ```
> // ./node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/grunt/index.js
> var child = ChildProcess.fork(
>   path.join(__dirname, 'grunt-wrapper.js'),
>   [
>     taskName,
>     '--pathToSails='+pathToSails,
>
>     '--gdsrc='+ pathToSails + '/node_modules'
>   ],
>   {
>     silent: true,       
>     stdio: 'pipe',
>     execArgv: []
>   }
> );
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a bug in Sails. You can apply the fix your self by replacing your Sails' file:

> ./node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/grunt/index.js

with the contents of  the following:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/balderdashy/sails/88ffc0ed9949f8c74ea390efb5610b0e378fa02c/lib/hooks/grunt/index.js

This is the file that will be in the Sails' release v12.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run in debug like simple node.js?

node --debug app.js